# Role of も in "犯人は死亡したもようです！"?

Tags: particle-も

What role is も playing in

> 犯人は死亡したもようです！

from first episode of *Death Note*?

Comment: [模様](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%A8%A1%E6%A7%98)

Answer (score 3):

It is not the particle も(+ようです), but 模様{もよう}(+です) is one word meaning *appearance* as commented.

> [模様](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E6%A8%A1%E6%A7%98/#je-75717)
>
> II〔有り様，様子〕
>
> どうも彼は来ない模様だ
> It looks 「as though [《米》 like] he's not coming.
>
> 火星には生物はいない模様である
> 「There is no sign of [There doesn't seem to be any] life on Mars.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, it would be the first character of 模様 (**も**よう) particularly for the meaning "state/condition." If I recall correctly, light is testing the death note and watching a news report? in that case, the sentence would mean

> "the criminal seems to be in a dying state"

(spoilered in case you would rather translate on your own)

Comment: もよう is a single word that here is basically a formal synonym of よう, you can't analyse it as 模＋様

Comment: As I see it, the problem is not so much in splitting up 模様 into も and よう as in translating 死亡した as *dy**ing***. I thought a downvote is a bit harsh.

Comment: @aguijonazo I downvoted it initially and reconsidered after, but it's too late to change it now, unless it gets edited. I think it would be better not to have answers that are just a guess without confirming anything, but I agree, it doesn't necessarily need to be downvoted.